# how to add Javascript files to Jenkins jelly file?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I couldn't find any where to on how to include my own javascript to jenkins jelly file. So far I have added jquery using the following

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
```

Say if I have myPageScripts.js in jenkins project,  is there anyway I can include my own javascript files there with script src?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it finally :) You can add it to your project path

Add all your custom js here.

projectName\src\main\webapp\myCustom.js

on Jelly file I can access that by

```
 <script src="${rootURL}/plugin/projectName/myCustom.js"/>
```